# Lightweight python editor for Mac

Tags: python, text-editor, ide

I am looking for a lightweight, fast and simple python file editor. I do not need fancy extensions or debugging capabilities, maybe a very simple syntax checker, and that a tab inserts 4 spaces. That's it.

I have been using `komodo-edit` for now, but this is very bulky, slow and not performant.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor is FOSS and supports Python "lexer" out of the box. The Addons Manager has several plugins for Python. For example, "Python IntelliSense" which is smart auto-completion and goto-definition.

The External Tools plugin allows to run Python scripts. https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText_plugins#Tool_to_run_Python_scripts

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will suggest [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac) which works well. However, I've grown to like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) which I find a bit more responsive. It supports lots of plugins, but you don't need to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the inbuilt IDLE for python which is very light weight, simple, customizable python editor. If you want, you could go for sublime text which is the best (best of best) python editor which doesn't have any plugins or plugin installer unless you install them. I would recommend sublime text. And also it has themes and color scheme to change or install using plugin installer if you need.

Sublime text - my personal favorite.